# Si se encuentra un resultado ¿Como Puedo Bloquear el formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo las validaciones para los campos de mi formulario, y una de estas, es que si el valor escrito en un campo, en este caso **rut_usu** se encuentra en la base de datos, se bloquee el formulario, y se auto enfoque el input nuevamente para modificar su valor. Esto lo estoy haciendo de esta forma, busca el valor correctamente, y me muestra el mensaje correcto, pero ¿Como podría hacer que se bloquee el formulario, si se encuentra un resultado?

Javascript

```
$("#rut_usu").focusout(function(){

$("#resultado").removeClass("hide");

//obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo
var parametros = {"rut_usu" : $("#rut_usu").val()};

//hace la búsqueda
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>C_Usuarios/consultar_rut',
    data: parametros,
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
        alert("error petición ajax");
    },success: function(data){                                                          
      if(data){ 

          $('#btn_insert').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#resultado').html('<span style="color:red;">Ya existe un usuario con ese Rut</span>');


               window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.focus();   
               window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.select();

               return false; 
        }  

        else{ 

          $("#resultado").addClass("hide");

           }

           return true;

         }

      });

    });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-2">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Rut</label>
      <input type="text" id="rut_usu" name="rut_usu" class="form-control" placeholder="18811942-5" autofocus>
      <div id="resultado"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Si existe un valor igual en la base de datos se muestra el mensaje del model dentro del div resultado.

Model

```
 public function consultar_rut($rut_usu){

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT rut_usu FROM usuarios WHERE rut_usu='$rut_usu'");
 $usuario = $query->row();

 if(empty($usuario)) {echo false;} //Si existe devolvemos false
 else {echo true; }//Si no existe, true.
}
```

**EDITADO**

Una de las personas de la comunidad, me ha ayudado, a dar con parte de la respuesta(la desmarque como aceptada porque no he logrado solucionar un aspecto dentro de la pregunta).Dentro del javascript tambien tengo lo siguiente para validar que un campo no este en blanco:

```
$("#pnombre").focusout(function(){

if($("#pnombre").val().length<1){

$("#pnombre").addClass("blanco");
$("#msg_pnom").removeClass("hide");

  window.document.r_usuarios.pnombre.focus();   
  window.document.r_usuarios.pnombre.select();    
  return false; 

}

   return true;
});

$("#pnombre").keypress(function(){

 $("#pnombre").removeClass("blanco");
 $("#msg_pnom").addClass("hide");


});
```

Con esto estoy hago que si se desenfoca el campo #pnombre, si esta vació, se bloquea el formulario y se auto enfoca, si le agrego las lineas con windows.id_form.id_campo y sus atributos, al tratar de validar el campo #rut_usu no me lo autoenfoca, y no se bloquean los campos del formulario. Si ingreso un valor del #rut_usu que esta en la base de datos, y luego clickeo en otro campo, que tiene la validación del windows,id_form  etc. se autoenfoca en ese campo aunque si se muestra el mensaje, sin embargo si clickeo fuera del formulario y no en otro campo, si  se enfoca #rut_usu.  Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hay que modificar un poco todo, sobre todo el Ajax, ya que no tienes bien el concepto:

> jQuery

```
<script>
$("#rut_usu").focusout(function(){
    $("#resultado").removeClass("hide");

    //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo
    var parametros = {"rut_usu" : $("#rut_usu").val()};

    //hace la búsqueda
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>C_Usuarios/consultar_rut',
        data: parametros,
        dataType: "html",
        error: function(){
            alert("error petición ajax");
        },success: function(data){                                                          
            if(data){ 
                $('#formButtonSubbmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#resultado').html('<span style="font-weight:bold;color:red;">Ya existe un usuario con ese Rut</span>');
            }else{ 
                $('#formButtonSubbmit').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#formButtonSubbmit').html('');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Lo que se ha realizado es, enviar los datos por Ajax y esperar una respuesta. Si la respuesta es TRUE, quiere decir que existe ya en la DB. Si es false, no existe y podemos continuar. Ten en cuenta que tienes que editar la ID del botón "formButtonSubbmit" por la tuya que uses. Lo que hace es poner el botón desactivado.

> PHP

```
public function consultar_rut($rut_usu){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT rut_usu FROM usuarios WHERE rut_usu='$rut_usu'");
    $usuario = $query->row();

    if(empty($usuario)) echo false; //Si no existe devolvemos false
    else echo true; //Si existe, true.
}
```

Lo que se ha modificado es la respuesta, para devolver true o false. El mensaje de error en sí, lo escribiremos desde el JS.

Probablemente necesites realizar algún par de ajustes para adecuarlo exactamente a como quieras que quede y como se ve el resto del formulario que no nos muestras, pero lo básico te funcionará con esto.

Saludos,

Comment: Esto no  Funciona, pero gracias por responder, no se muestra el mensaje ni se bloquea el boton, si cambie el id por cierto. Creo que aquí f(empty($usuario)) return true; debería de ser false, se supone que ahí no encuentra el resultado, si lo encuentra se ejecuta en el else

Comment: Efectivamente, hay que cambiar o negar el return. Cambia true por false y debería funcionar.

Comment: También  lo probé de esa forma, el else del javascript se ejecuta siempre, nunca se ejecuta el if

Comment: Haz una prueba rápida, cambia return por echo en el PHP. Al no tener la parte del PHP completa hice una pequeña aproximación simplemente con echo.

Comment: Ese es todo el php, el otro es el controlador que pasa la variable al model, solo hace eso :P, con el echo me funciono bien, gracias

Comment: Perfecto, un placer servir de ayuda. He actualizado el código que te puse para que ya quede correctamente. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una manera seria añadiendo el atributo disable de esta forma.
`$("#formulario :input").attr("disabled", true);`

En tuca caso seria así:

```
 if ($("#resultado").html(data) > 0) {

     //window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.focus();
     $("#formulario :input").attr("disabled", true);   
     //window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.select();    
     return false;
```

};

Tienes más información acerca de *disable* aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero el  problema es el if, ya que al mostrar un mensaje no se esta ejecutando, porque no es un valor, o al menos eso creo, ya que he utilizado           window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.focus();   
         window.document.r_usuarios.rut_usu.select();    
         return false;  para validar los otros campos y funciona bien

Comment: Esta respuesta no da una solución como tal, la comprobación se debe hacer en el success de ajax, no fuera de la petición, el código es erróneo si se realiza fuera, data no estará declarado...